# Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time error while adding 4 slider values

Tags: swift, xcode, uislider

I tried to add these 4 slider values, but received this error, how do I solve it? Code:

```
@IBAction func mathValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let total = MathCriASlider.value + MathCriBSlider.value + MathCriCValue.value + MathCriDSlider.value
    mathValue.text = "/(total)"
}
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project (`CMD + K`) and building again, if that doesn't work, restart Xcode, if that doesn't work restart your mac.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an error because you aren't referencing "sender". @EmilioPelaez has a point - but if **all** four sliders are hooked up to `mathValueChanged`, should you (at least logically) be addressing the `sender` slider?

Comment: It makes sense to use the ivars instead of `sender` if you want your action to add the values of all sliders. Personally I would create the method without the parameter, but Xcode adds it by default, and OP seems like a newbie, so they get a pass. It shouldn't cause this error though, it should only happen on really complex stuff, unless OP's computer was being slowed down by something else.

Comment: Am I OP? Anyway thank you for your help, and yes I am a newbie.

Comment: Yes, you're "OP", which means "original poster" - the creator of this question or thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustrating for sure, I'm surprised to see this in more recent versions of Swift. In the past I've just had to break down the expression. e.g.

```
let A = MathCriASlider.value
let B = MathCriBSlider.value
let C = MathCriCSlider.value
let D = MathCriDSlider.value
let total = A + B + C + D
```

And you may even need to compute a pair of subtotals if it still complains.

The second line needs fixing, your string interpolation is wrong. Use

```
mathValue.text = "\(total)"  // I changed the slash to a backslash
```